# Centerized the rest of the grid items

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WoGUQ.png)

I was try to make like the example one for tablet layout, here's my code :

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-8 justify-items-center px-8 mt-8 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4">
 <div class="w-28 aspect-video bg-green-500"></div>
 <div class="w-28 aspect-video bg-green-500"></div>
 <div class="w-28 aspect-video bg-green-500"></div>
 <div class="w-28 aspect-video bg-green-500"></div>
 <div class="w-28 aspect-video bg-green-500"></div>
 <div class="w-28 aspect-video bg-green-500"></div>
 <div class="w-28 aspect-video bg-green-500"></div>
 <div class="w-28 aspect-video bg-green-500"></div>
</div>
```

So, there's any alternative for that?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider doubling the grid column track count, and then offseting the items by one column:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-4 gap-8 justify-items-center px-8 mt-8 md:grid-cols-6 lg:grid-cols-8">
  <div class="w-28 aspect-video bg-green-500 col-span-2"></div>
  <div class="w-28 aspect-video bg-green-500 col-span-2"></div>
  <div class="w-28 aspect-video bg-green-500 col-span-2"></div>
  <div class="w-28 aspect-video bg-green-500 col-span-2"></div>
  <div class="w-28 aspect-video bg-green-500 col-span-2"></div>
  <div class="w-28 aspect-video bg-green-500 col-span-2"></div>
  <div class="w-28 aspect-video bg-green-500 col-span-2 md:max-lg:col-start-2"></div>
  <div class="w-28 aspect-video bg-green-500 col-span-2 md:max-lg:col-start-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the alternative, but if I made some div, should I do the same as you do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use flex for that instead of grid and setting the max-with to the padding + gap + columns width, like:

```
<div class="flex gap-8 p-8 mx-auto flex-wrap justify-center max-w-[20] md:max-w-[29rem] lg:max-w-[38rem]">
  <div class="w-28 aspect-video bg-green-500"></div>
  <div class="w-28 aspect-video bg-green-500"></div>
  <div class="w-28 aspect-video bg-green-500"></div>
  <div class="w-28 aspect-video bg-green-500"></div>
  <div class="w-28 aspect-video bg-green-500"></div>
  <div class="w-28 aspect-video bg-green-500"></div>
  <div class="w-28 aspect-video bg-green-500"></div>
  <div class="w-28 aspect-video bg-green-500"></div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/4Sexse1HX4

Comment: it is still the same shape if i made some div?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't understand your question. What do you mean by 'if I made some div'?